# Ubuntu: adding program to Startup Applications through a script

Tags: ubuntu, boot, automation

I know that on Ubuntu you can add a program into "Startup Applications" by going through a few  mouse click. Is it possible to achieve the same through some shell script?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd like to check [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/Xsession.5.html). Especially, the "CUSTOMIZING THE STARTUP PROCEDURE" section.